# FTP account for just one directory

Tags: permissions, ftp, vsftpd

**Background information:**

I'm using Serverpilot to manage my Ubuntu server which doesn't provide any FTP service.

- There is a user: `serverpilot`
- With the home directory: `/srv/users/serverpilot/`
- And there is a website running in this directory: `/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/website/public/`.

**What I want:**

Now I would like to have a FTP account which can only read and write to this directory: `/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/website/public/ftpdir/`.

**What I've tried:**

- I've installed vsftpd: `sudo apt-get install vsftpd`
- Created a new user with that directory as home: `sudo useradd -m -d /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/website/public/ftpdir ftpuser` (wich is probably not a good idea to have a home directory of a user in another users home directory)
- I've changed the password with `sudo passwd ftpuser`
- Edited the default vsftpd configuration with `sudo vi /etc/vsftpd.conf`

  - `local_enable=YES` so the `ftpuser` can be used as ftp login
  - `write_enable=YES` the user is able to write
  - `chroot_local_user=YES` can't access anything outside it's home dir
  - `pam_service_name=ftp` because I was getting a [530 Login incorrect error](https://askubuntu.com/a/413694)
- And opened my firewall with: `sudo ufw allow 21/tcp`

**The problems:**

- Other users beside the `ftpuser` can also be used as FTP login. I just want to have 1 ftp user and not allow other system users to use FTP.
- The `ftpuser` can also SSH into the server.
- I'm getting a `553 error: could not create file` error when trying to upload a file, to fix this I came across this question: https://askubuntu.com/a/320186 but I don't think this is the right way because the file should be owned by the `serverpilot` user, not the `ftpuser` user. The website running under the `serverpilot` user should proces the uploaded files.

**How I've solved it before:**

In the past on another server I've changed the directory ownership and after adding these extra vsftpd configuration options it was finally working:

```
file_open_mode=0775
local_umask=022
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
```

But on that server I had problems with processing the uploaded files because of the ownership, so there I'm using the `file_get_contents()` PHP function to get the files over the web instead of direct access them on the server which isn't that nice.

**The final question:**

How can I simply have 1 ftp login which can read and write to a directory in a users home directory where the ownership stays on the user where the home directory is from?

*Sorry for the duplication, I've also asked this question on Ask Ubuntu without any answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/774701/ftp-account-for-just-one-directory maybe more luck over here*